# nuget pack a PCL for net451 and dnxcore50

Tags: c#, nuget-package, portable-class-library, dnx

I have a PCL project that targets .NET Framework 4.5 + ASP.NET Core 5.0. That means PCL Profile 75 according to the contents of the .csproj file.

I added a basic .nuspec file with the same name as the .csproj file.

Now I do `nuget pack foo.csproj`. In the generated .nupkg I get a folder named `/lib/portable-net45` but I expected something like `/lib/portable-net45+dnxcore50` so that I can use the package in a DNX project.

Is this intended behavior? How would I go about creating a NuGet package for multiple targets (after all that is what the PCL is for) without manually putting together a folder structure for the NuGet package?

I (the buildserver actually) have built numerous NuGet packages in the way I described above and I expected it to work the same way with PCL projects.

Comment: Why does "does not work?" have a question mark?  We need "does not work!!" with a good description of the error message to get somewhere.

Comment: I believe I described clearly what I expect and what I get instead. There is no error message, there is a .nupkg with a wrong folder name in it. But I'll remove the question for you.

Comment: Have you verified that you indeed *cannot* add the NuGet package to your *ASP.NET Core 5* project? I actually don't think you need to (or even should) specify *dnxcore50* in the folder path, I think that *portable-* is enough.